# Copying contents of command prompt into a file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a code for my project.In that a menu will be displayed to the user and user selects an option then it displays the pre-defined output.That's all fine but i want that data which is displayed on command prompt to be copied into a file to analyze the data ca anyone help me with code:(

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You say “command prompt” but it sounds like you are referring to a console based application and you want to respond to user input given to your program.  Where does this data you want to analyze come from?  Does a user type it in?

Comment: Please make significant improvements to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61230717/edit).  We do not provide code for you on this site, we help you to fix a specific replicable issue with your own. We can only do that, once you've provided it, and included sufficient information for us to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to do it from the Java itself with Java File API or so. If so please check FileWriter class. Other way is you can follow this https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/save-command-line-output-file-windows-mac-linux/